# Checking code with FIT

Tags: java, eclipse, static-analysis, fit-framework

I've written fit check for my code but for some reason it doesn't work due to `class not found exception`.

this is the exception:
[image]

these are the folders:
[image]

this is the fit code:
[image]

this is the HTML file of the checks...

[image]

According to the exception it's not a problem with my code as much as it's a problem with where the class file is located. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: advice: do not name Package with a capital letter at the begin of name.

Comment: Looks like you class CheckSubscriber is not in your project(see label of the file).

Comment: where would you put the class? according to what i know the class should be in fixture package in the main project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse do not recognize your class as Java class, because the fixtures folder is not **Source Folder**. So CheckSubscribers is not compiled when you run project.

Try to create Fixture as the source folder [using wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-wizard-source-folder.htm).

If purpose of creating CheckSubscriber is testing good practice is the following standard [Maven layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).
So simply create source folders: **src/java** to contain project classes and **src/test** to contain test classes.